# Unique rank in Excel

Tags: excel, grouping, ranking

I have a spreadsheet where I want a Unique rank with groups, I've been searching online but can't quite get it right, this is what I want (there are 2000 rows in total) in the rank column

[image]

I've used sumproduct, which is working but when I try to use COUNTIF, it does seem to respect the group

Comment: What COUNTIF() did you try?

Comment: Is your data always sorted like the picture?

Comment: Is there something else that helps determine the ranking of tied percentages or is it just based on location in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can figure out you want:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,">"&B2)+COUNTIFS(A2:A$2000,A2,B2:B$2000,B2)
```

[image]

Comment: This has nailed it, thanks. I definitely don't class myself as and advanced user, as you can probably tell!